# Restore to the Emulator from the Server?

Tags: android

I am using 2.1 platform.......I am able to Retrieve all the **Contacts and SMS** from the Emulator and copy in to a text file and store it in a server with a particular User Account.Also I have to Restore these Contacts and SMS to the Emulator back.I don't know how to do it.Now I am using the AVD and Eclipse to run the Android Project.I am going to buy a new android mobile and restore these Contacts and SMS back to that mobile.I retrieved the Contacts using **CURSOR and CONTENT_URI**  and SMS using **CURSOR**.

How can I do the **RESTORE** to the Emulator back from the text file in server ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the text file and save the data in cursor's object?? If yes, the follow [this](http://wubbahed.com/2007/12/21/android-development-contacts/) link. You will need to add every contact by using some loop.

And to get values from cursor you can use [this](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/query-contacts-data.html) link for reference.

Edit: here the code from second link

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Contacts.People.NAME, "Test Name");
// add it to the database
ContentURI newPerson = getContentResolver().insert(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, values);

// assign the new phone number to the person
values.clear();
values.put(Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID, newPerson.getPathLeaf());
values.put(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER, "(800) 466-4411");
// insert the new phone number in the database
getContentResolver().insert(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I won't be able to explain this, so try to visit the first link.

Comment: The first link is not loading.second link is OK .......I will check .thanks for your reply